# Specific html within wordpress loop

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to setup a wordpress slider, how can I achieve exact below result within a wordpress loop

```
            <div id="carousel">
                <img src="slide1.png" alt="" class="slide" />
                <img src="slide2.png" alt="" class="slide" />
                <img src="slide3.png" alt="" class="slide" />
            </div>

            <ul id="carousel-descriptions">
                <li class="desc current">Slide 1 Description Goes Here</li>
                <li class="desc">Slide 2 Description Goes Here</li>
                <li class="desc">Slide 3 Description Goes Here</li>
            </ul>

            <div id="carousel-controls">
                <span class="control current">Show Me<br>Slide 1</span>
                <span class="control">Show Me<br>Slide 2</span>
                <span class="control">Show Me<br>Slide 3</span>
            </div>
```

for example, I want to show above code within

```
 $my_query = new WP_Query('cat=49&showposts=4&orderby=RAND');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
?>

 above code

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Please do let me know if there is any other way to achieve the same result but orderby=RAND is important for me

BR

Comment: is the css class `.current` on the first post per section important? is the image the featured imge aka post thumbnail?

Comment: yes, the css class is important to show the current item highlightes. images are post thumbnail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`rewind_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts) to reset a loop and run it multiple times:

```
<?php

$my_query = new WP_Query('cat=49&showposts=4&orderby=RAND');
?>
<div id="carousel">
<?php
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    // output each slide
endwhile;
?>
</div>
<?php

$my_query->rewind_posts();
?>
<ul id="carousel-descriptions">
<?php
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    // output each desc
endwhile;
?>
</ul>
<?php

$my_query->rewind_posts();
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Or save the results into variables and run loop once like :

$carousel_descriptions .= 'Slide 1 Description Goes Here';

then after the loop its finished just echo those variables.